# Getting the direction is Incoming or Outgoing

Tags: java, android

In order to be a default phone app, It is mandatory to implement `InCallService` along with `meta-data` tags in the manifest and using `CALL_PHONE` permission.

**What i have done so far :**

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<service
            android:name=".InCallServiceImplementation"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INCALL_SERVICE">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.telecom.IN_CALL_SERVICE_UI"
                android:value="true" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.telecom.IN_CALL_SERVICE_RINGING"
                android:value="true" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.telecom.InCallService" />
            </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

Having been asked for default, having the CALL_PHONE permission granted by user too. 
Below is my InCallServiceImplementation.java which extends InCallService

```
    @Override
    public void onCallAdded(Call call)
    {
        super.onCallAdded(call);
        Log.d("InCallService :", "Added a new call.. \n");
        new OngoingCall().setCall(call);

        Log.d("InCallService :", "FOUND DIRECTION FOR INCOMING :" + IsInComingCall + ".. \n");

        if (IsInComingCall)
        {
            // START ACTIVITY FOR INCOMING CALL
            //IncomingCallActivity.start(this, call);
        }
        else
        {
            // START ACTIVITY FOR OUTGOING CALL
            //DialerActivity.start(this, call);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallRemoved(Call call)
    {
        super.onCallRemoved(call);
        Log.d("InCallService :", "Call is removed.. \n");
        new OngoingCall().setCall(null);
    }
```

And below is my OngoingCall.java class

```
    private Object callback = new Call.Callback() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(Call call, int newState) {
            super.onStateChanged(call, newState);
            state.onNext(newState);
        }
    };

    public final void setCall(@Nullable Call value) 
    {
        if (call != null) 
        {
            call.unregisterCallback((Call.Callback)callback);
        }

        if (value != null) 
        {
            value.registerCallback((Call.Callback)callback);
            state.onNext(value.getState());
        }

        call = value;
    }

    public void answer() 
    {
        assert call != null;
        call.answer(VideoProfile.STATE_AUDIO_ONLY);
    }

    public void hangup() 
    {
        assert call != null;
        call.disconnect();
    }
```

**How it is working :** 
It is working fine if i makes dial or call from My App, Or even if dial from manufacturer phone app, it launches my `DialerActivity` if the `if-else` is removed from function `onCallAdded`

**What is the problem then :**

Even if any incoming call is coming it is still showing `DialerActivity` which shows outgoing call is in progress Screen. I have 2 different activities for incoming and outgoing call.

**What resolution i am looking for :**

How can i find is the call is incoming or outgoing, the call direction. So that appropriate layout can be presented to the user.

**What are the efforts taken for studying or search :**

I always found it very hard to understand what google documentation is meant for?

Found it here [Call.Details](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call.Details.html#getCallDirection()) the direction can be taken. I searched a lot and again found [Build a Calling App](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged) which lacs many things of implementation. Just some overview and some incomplete samples shown with a lot of theory. I found [Simple Phone](https://github.com/arekolek/simple-phone) but it is developed in kotlin. The same project is in java named as [Custom Phone Dialer](https://github.com/Abror96/CustomPhoneDialer) which has not implemented the direction. Nor i found any proper and step by step guides from google documentation. If a developer tries to read their sample programs, many variables and functions are missing, its useless to read and spend a lot time over studying it.

Comment: Formatting: 1. each link should have a different number in the `[]` brackets. 2. All link references are commonly put at the end of the file after all of your regular text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Call state is ringing :

```
if (call.getState() == Call.STATE_RINGING)
```

Its a incoming call

And if call state is connecting :

```
else if (call.getState() == Call.STATE_CONNECTING)
```

Its a outgoing call